# drupal webform Confirmation Message

Tags: webforms

I have got a webform in a iframe and its quite long when a customer fills the details and clicks submit they just see a white screen because the page has been scrolled down due to the form been very long and they have to scroll back up to see the confirmation message.is there anyway when they click submit the scroll resets?

Answer (score 1):

> you can use this js code

```
 $('.page-node-webform #edit-actions #edit-save').click(function() {

                return confirm('Are you sure?');

            });
```